# How can I decode getData from a contract method call

Tags: transactions, calldata

I'm using myContractInstance.myMethod.getData() to be able to serialize a transaction:

```
// Get the call data, so you can call the contract through some other means
var myCallData = myContractInstance.myMethod.getData(param1 [, param2, ...]);
// myCallData = '0x45ff3ff6000000000004545345345345..'
```

The transaction is later excuted later (by another person):

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({"data": myCallData});
```

However, I want the other person, who will execute the transaction, to be able to decode `myCallData`, so they know that they're not transfering a huge amount. I can't find a way to do that in the documentation, however.

Is there a friendly way to decode `myCallData`, and make it readable again for the user (other than breaking up the data ABI pieces myself)?

Peter.

Comment: Have you looked  to see if [RLP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP) might offer something?

Comment: RLP seems a bit over the top. I would follow the first example in the [Contract ABI documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#examples), which describes how the `data` is encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ether value of the transaction is not part of this `.getData()`, it has to be set separately: `web3.eth.sendTransaction({"data": myCallData, "value": 123});`

On a different note, the user will need to trust the decoding tool. So why not offer a way for the user to replay this `.getData()` and confirm the byte-wise equality?

Comment: Hi @Xavier, with 'amount' I meant a custom value from my contract, not Ethers. It seems there's no other option than decoding the data myself, but I appreciate your note on trust, and your suggestion to let the user replay `getDate()` and compare the output.